# How to search for a sentence using keywords till the end of a string in python

Tags: python, file

I am struck in a small logical part

my code is here

```
def find_between( string, first, last ):
    list1 = []
    try:
        start = string.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = string.index( last, start )
        list1.append(string[start:end])
        print(list1)
    except ValueError:
        return ""

with open("sample.txt")as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)

    find_between( data, "*CHI:  " , "%mor:  " )
```

my sample.txt contains :

```
*CHI:   I saw a giraffe and a elephant .
%mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|a n|giraffe coord|and det:art|a
    n|elephant .
%gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|2|OBJ 5|4|CONJ 6|7|DET 7|5|COORD 8|2|PUNCT
*CHI:   <that> [/] (.) that (i)s it . [+ bch]
%mor:   pro:dem|that cop|be&3S pro:per|it .
%gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|2|PRED 4|2|PUNCT
*CHI:   I saw an elephant go swimming .
%mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|a n|elephant v|go part|swim-PRESP .
%gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|5|SUBJ 5|2|COMP 6|5|OBJ 7|2|PUNCT
*CHI:   <I saw eleph> [//] I saw the <g> [/] giraffe and the elephant <s>
    [//] drop ball in the pool .
%mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|the n|giraffe coord|and det:art|the
    n|elephant n|drop n|ball prep|in det:art|the n|pool .
%gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|2|OBJ 5|4|CONJ 6|9|DET 7|9|MOD 8|9|MOD
    9|5|COORD 10|9|NJCT 11|12|DET 12|10|POBJ 13|2|PUNCT
*CHI:   I saw giraffe swimming in the pool to get that ball .
%mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST n|giraffe part|swim-PRESP prep|in det:art|the
    n|pool inf|to v|get pro:dem|that n|ball .
```

I should return all the sentence that is between "*CHI: " and "%mor:    "
my code only brings the first line that is

```
I saw a giraffe and a elephant
```

help me by iterating till the end of the string and i should be able to print all those sentence that is between "*CHI: " and "%mor:    "

Comment: Use regular expressions

Comment: @PeMaCN I am finding it hard to do in regular expression more over I dont have any idea about it. Can you help me build this logic. Thanks!

Comment: What if there is %gra in between *CHI and %mor. Should that be returned as well ?

Comment: @VineethSai No the start will always be *CHI:  " and end will always be "%mor:  "  %gra will not occur in between them, so you need not return it

Comment: Do they occur one after the other all the time ?

Comment: @VineethSai Yes they will always occur one after the other but there might be "n" number of lines in between the start and the end , so i should return all the sentence that is between the start and the end

Comment: Is it ok if you search only for `CHI:` and get from that to the end of line?

Comment: @PeMaCN It wont work in my case because there might be some words in the next lines also, I should not miss those words/sentence. The suitable way will be to search between *CHI: and %mor

Comment: If you see in this case :


`*CHI:   <I saw eleph> [//] I saw the <g> [/] giraffe and the elephant <s>
    [//] drop ball in the pool .
%mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|the n|giraffe coord|and det:art|the
    n|elephant n|drop n|ball prep|in det:art|the n|pool .`


The end of the line will be <s> but then you will be missing :-   [//] drop ball in the pool . So the best method is to search from *CHI:  and %mor

Comment: I managed to get a solution. Will write the answer.

Comment: @PeMaCN Yeah any help is encouraged. Can you post your answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used the regular expression and simple string instead of a file, but it is the same principle. Check the working code:

```
import re

s = """
    *CHI:   I saw a giraffe and a elephant .
    %mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|a n|giraffe coord|and det:art|a 
        n|elephant .
    %gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|2|OBJ 5|4|CONJ 6|7|DET 7|5|COORD 8|2|PUNCT
    *CHI:   <that> [/] (.) that (i)s it . [+ bch]
    %mor:   pro:dem|that cop|be&3S pro:per|it .
    %gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|2|PRED 4|2|PUNCT
    *CHI:   I saw an elephant go swimming .
    %mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|a n|elephant v|go part|swim-PRESP .
    %gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|5|SUBJ 5|2|COMP 6|5|OBJ 7|2|PUNCT
    *CHI:   <I saw eleph> [//] I saw the <g> [/] giraffe and the elephant <s>
        [//] drop ball in the pool .
    %mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST det:art|the n|giraffe coord|and det:art|the
        n|elephant n|drop n|ball prep|in det:art|the n|pool .
    %gra:   1|2|SUBJ 2|0|ROOT 3|4|DET 4|2|OBJ 5|4|CONJ 6|9|DET 7|9|MOD 8|9|MOD
        9|5|COORD 10|9|NJCT 11|12|DET 12|10|POBJ 13|2|PUNCT
    *CHI:   I saw giraffe swimming in the pool to get that ball .
    %mor:   pro:sub|I v|see&PAST n|giraffe part|swim-PRESP prep|in det:art|the
        n|pool inf|to v|get pro:dem|that n|ball .
    """

result = re.findall('(?<=CHI:)(.*?)(?=%mor)', s, flags=re.S)
print(result)
```

Comment: if %gra is in between, It is being printed.

Comment: @PeMaCN it was very helpful please provide me links where I ca learn REGEX

Comment: I don't know any specific resource for learning regular expressions but with just googling you can find lots of useful stuff like tutorials, trying your regular expressions online etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do it without regex, although I'm still not sure if `%gra` is allowed to print in between.

```
def find_between( string, first, last ):
    flag = True
    try:
        buffer = ""
        op_string = ""
        for line in string:
            if first in line:
                buffer += line
                flag = True

            elif last in line:
                op_string += buffer 
                buffer = "" # flush buffer
                flag = False

            elif flag is True:
                buffer += line

        print(op_string)

    except ValueError:
        return ""

with open("sample.txt")as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    #print(data)

    find_between( data, "*CHI:  " , "%mor:  " )
```